# Email not sending using Javascript SMTP

Tags: javascript

I am having problems while using Javascript SMTP to send emails.I first tried in PHP but it didn't work so I chose JavaScript,I have been looking this for a week.
MY HTML CODE:

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" method="post">
    <h3>Checkout</h3>
    <h4>Get your reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Full Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" name="subject" id="subject" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Type your Address Here...." name="message" id="message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" onclick="sendemail(this.form)">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form> 
</div>
</body>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```js
function sendemail(form) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var address = document.getElementById("message").value;

    Email.send({
    Host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    Username : "shaheermkhan786@gmail.com",
    Password : "xxxxxxx", // My Password
    To : 'crispytntoffical@gmail.com',
    From : "Sender Email " + email,
    Subject : "Phone Number " + subject,
    Body : "Address " + address,
    }).then(
        message => alert("Order has been placed successfully")
    );
}
```

Comment: What are you getting in error?

Comment: Above other possible issues, gmail is finicky to use as smtp: https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10572126?hl=en

Comment: Have you disabled security from your gmail account? you have to change security settings 1) turn on [lesssecureapps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and 2) [Click continue](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: The possible reason is, you haven't turned on less secure sign-in in your google account. To do this 1) goto your google account security tab -> 2.) turn on Less secure app access.  ( URL - https://myaccount.google.com/security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code as SMTP.js:

```js
/* SmtpJS.com - v3.3.2 */
var Email = { send: function (a) { return new Promise(function (n, e) { a.nocache = Math.floor(1e6 * Math.random() + 1), a.Action = "Send"; var t = JSON.stringify(a); Email.ajaxPost("https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtpjs.aspx?", t, function (e) { n(e) }) }) }, ajaxPost: function (e, n, t) { var a = Email.createCORSRequest("POST", e); a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), a.onload = function () { var e = a.responseText; null != t && t(e) }, a.send(n) }, ajax: function (e, n) { var t = Email.createCORSRequest("GET", e); t.onload = function () { var e = t.responseText; null != n && n(e) }, t.send() }, createCORSRequest: function (e, n) { var t = new XMLHttpRequest; return "withCredentials" in t ? t.open(e, n, !0) : "undefined" != typeof XDomainRequest ? (t = new XDomainRequest).open(e, n) : t = null, t } };
```